# Changin features' pointRadius based on the current zoom level

Tags: openlayers-2, features, style

I need to have my features change their `pointRadius` based on the current `Zoom` level. My questions are:

1. Would it be possible to use `Rule Based Styling` techniques to overcome the problem?
2. If yes, it will work on `map zoom changed` as well?
3. If no, what are the alternative solutions and what you offer instead? (except redrawing features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

```
//exmp for zoom level 5
var new_style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
new_style.pointRadius = 5;
vector.styleMap.styles['default'].defaultStyle = new_style;
vector.redraw(true);
```

---

**Update 1**

if you want to catch zoom event, you should register your `zoomend` to map.

```
map.events.register(type, obj, listener);
```

example code:

```
 map.events.register("zoomend", map, function() {
     if(zoom == 3){
        console.info("your zoom is at level 3");
     }else{
        console.warn("your zoom is not at level 3");
     }         
        });
```

---

try to use following code.

```
var zoom = map.getZoom();
var result;

var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
    pointRadius: "${radius}"
  } , {
    context: {
      radius: function(feature) {
      if (zoom == 5){
        result = 5 * defaultPointRadius;
       }else{
        result = 2 * defaultPointRadius;
       }
        return result
      }
    }
  );

var layer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {
    strategies: [strategy],
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({"default": style})});
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks Aragon, I will give it a try soon. BTW, should I set the `defaultPointRadius` or that's internal?

Comment: it is only variable, you can define what you want. good luck :)

Comment: this works fine, but not when the zoom level is changed. Is there any way to fire it again when user changes the zoom level? I have lot's of layers and features, I really don't want to redraw them every time.

Comment: @Mahdi, i have updated my answer. hope it helps you...

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I already have that in my code which is redrawing all the features when the zoom level is changes, my question is how to bind it to the `style` so it doesn't need to redraw everything each time zoom changes. Is it even possible?

Comment: @Mahdi, i have updated my answer. check out update 2.

Comment: thanks for all of your helps, I learned a lot, but finally I just went for the redrawing features ... however I will try to change it to something more optimal in the near future. Thanks again.